# Blazor WASM in a single project?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0, visual-studio-project

I noticed with .NET8, whenever you create a new Blazor project, it always generates two projects instead (a "main" and a ".Client" project), no matter what combination of options you choose. Is there a way to create ONLY one project like it was in .NET6?

And also, what's the purpose of having it split into two projects?

Comment: The two projects are because a standalone wasm project often is paired with a server side app - typically, a web api - to handle your data on the backend. I suppose it's a bit of a crutch but its a common setup to have an api backend along with a wasm front end. They used to also provide a "Shared" project as well - the idea was that both projects could access models/interfaces from the shared project and save you the hassle of having to duplicate the code on both ends (so you see, the api can serialize the models, and the client can deserialize them using the same classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App" template in Visual Studio to create a single project Blazor WASM app. "Blazor Web App" is the Blazor template that creates 2 projects, server and client, as you have found.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this is possible with MudBlazor too? (as this is my ultimate goal here)

Comment: Very likely it is possible. You can try their own templates as well: https://github.com/MudBlazor/Templates (in this case, I think you are looking for `dotnet new mudblazor --interactivity WebAssembly --all-interactive`

Comment: Yes but this creates two projects, too. There is no way to scaffold a WASM-only-template in the CLI.  Or can the WASM-Only output be generated off of it to be hosted on static storage?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 projects one is the "ASP NET Hosted" option I believe. The Shared project being the ASP NET back end, which will serve the Blazor WASM front end to the end user.

The templates change and have many options, these options might not be immediately apparent or described well enough through the Visual Studio "New Project" interface.

I find using `dotnet new --help` from the console helps me find what I am looking for.

For instance, asking for help on a specific template will list the many options in terms of flags.  So if I want individual authentication, a single project style template, and I don't want to use top level statements in my `Program.cs` I can enter the command:

```bash
dotnet new blazorwasm --help
```

After a quick read I can see I need the following options:

```bash
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted false --auth individual --use-program-main true --name testapp
```

> Note: at the time of writing, the `--hosted` option is default to false, so this is redundant for information purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to having the blazor wasm selfhosted on the api anymore ... its a new way of building your app... this is only explicit for .net8

The app is now using different rendering modes so you can choose between different modes per Page/Component ... instead of having to choose between wasm and server for the whole project.

They added also another rendering Mode Server Side Rendering (Similar to Razor Pages).

The Client project represent WASM components and the Main represents Server Side rendering or Interactive Server Side (Old blazor Server).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwZdtLEtROA