# Is there no Blazor Server App template anymore?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to develop a Blazor Server application. Not Web App, not WebAssembly App, but a Blazor Server App. On my work computer I have several templates to choose from when I filter for Blazor (Blazor Web App, Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App, Blazor WebAssembly App Empty, Blazor Server App, Blazor Server App Empty).
In instaled Visual Studio 2022 on my personal laptop so I can start a private Blazor project. But there are only two options: Blazor WebApp and Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App. Where is the rest?
So I tried to create Blazor Server App using CLI `dotnet new blazorserver -o BlazorServerApp` which yielded an error, there is no such template as blazorserver. How is that possible?
Was Blazor Server replaced by Blazor Web App? I am so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is confusing.

Get to this screen on Blazor Web App and choose Server and Global.  You get one Server project, same as before.

[image]

This creates a project where *Interactivity* is set to *InteractiveServer* at the top level:

```cs
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
```

There's an answer here that shows how to use the command line [which contains some useful information]:

[Blazor WASM in a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77922926/blazor-wasm-in-a-single-project/77923204#77923204)

Comment: Personally I think MS made a big mistake in the way they built the template.  There are some options that need a government health warning.

Comment: Wanted to add / link a recent similar question.  I find that using `dotnet new --help` is far more descriptive than the visual studio UI and will help you find the template you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77922926/blazor-wasm-in-a-single-project/77923204#77923204